3 of 6 1m_DEMs not loading; CRS issue
I downloaded six adjacent 1m Grayscale DEM from The National Map.
When I load them into QGIS only 3 of the 6 appear as expected, the other three are just gray (no data)
I started a new project in QGIS 3.34.8-Prizren
Dragged and dropped the six GEOTIFF files into the layers panel.
I got popup about transforming UTM 13N+NAD83 to WGS84
--I have tried two times using the two most appropriate selections
--Both give the same results
I'm new to GIS.

Without pics, or a description of where you got the data from it is difficult to assist. It sounds like corrupted data, what are your Rasters' min and max values. What do the properties of the raster look like in those cases of grey scale? Have you tried loading just one of the problematic rasters first? Have you tried loading the rasters / querying the rasters any other way- like in Python?

I can't add images as I have not used Stack Exchange enough.
The data came from USGS apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader.
I selected my area of interest, selected 1 meter DEM and they are downloaded as a bona fide GEOTIFF. Since they are adjacent dems, they "should" all have a common CRS. Certainly each dem has differing low elevation and high elevation. If you simply view them side-by-side they are different shades, which QGIS can fix with Virtual Raster normalization.

I have found the source maps in question have corrupted Band 1 metadata. The maximum and minimum elevation are just gobbledygook.
It had nothing to do with CRS conversion.
